# Cross domain Webservice Call in Jquery

Tags: jquery, blackberry-webworks

i'm trying to invoke .net webservice in Jquery/Javascript for Blackberry webworks application but got error.

My code

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: { aUserName: '3007800000', aPassword: '24hitec0', DeviceID: '2' },
            url: "http://50.57.84.5/MobiTicker_mktService/MobileTicker.asmx?op=Login",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown); console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
```

and error is "**Error: jQuery1101008052381855433821_1371129501634 was not called**"

Webservice also have **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** problem.

anybody have any idea to resolve this?

Best Regards,

Comment: Does the web service support JSONP? It seems to be a soap web service. Please check the webservice reply in your developer tools, it should contain JavaScript that calls a dynamically generated callback like jQuery1101008052381855433821_1371129501634.

Comment: i think it support SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2
have you any idea how to invoke this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/, as the web service apparantly doesn't offer JSONP

Comment: Yes i have tried this and got following errors,

**status: string 'error'
jquery.soap.js (line 440)

a:object  isXMLDoc(a):false  a.responseText:string  isXMLDoc(a.responseText):false  a.responseXML:null  isXMLDoc(a.responseXML):false

jquery.soap.js (line 440)

c:string  isXMLDoc(c):false  c.responseText:undefined  isXMLDoc(c.responseText):false  c.responseXML:undefined  isXMLDoc(c.responseXML):false**

Comment: My Code is here 

   $.soap({
   url: 'http://50.57.84.5/MobiTicker_mktService/MobileTicker.asmx',
   method: 'Login',
   namespaceQualifier: 'Login',
   namespaceUrl: 'http://tempuri.org/',
    soap12: true,
                returnJson: false,
                params: {
                    aUserName: '3007800000',
                    aPassword: '24hitec0',
                    DeviceID: '2'
                },
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (string) {

                }
            });